# I have a 14/3 wire coming off 14/2 with power at fixture looking for diagram for proper wire connection

Tags: wiring

I have extinguishing 14/3 wire coming off 14/2 with power at light/fixture going to 15A combination switch/outlet on outside wall of a room .  I had to disconnect for demo and forgot to take a pic of how it was wired to hook it back up. Looking for diagram for proper wire connection on both ends to keep outlet constant.

Comment: "extinguishing"? Should that be "existing"? If not, what do you mean, as that's an odd term unless there's actually a fire. Pictures of what you've got now (at the light, the switch and the outlet) would be most helpful, just [edit] them into your post by dragging & dropping - the site will upload & host them for you.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?